# How to do efficent query to replace $exists in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb

I have a MongoDB collection with various data in it. (about millions)

These data have a data struct like `{k: {a:1,b:2,c:{},...}}` and I don't know extactly what in it.

Now I wanna do a counting on this collection to return me the total elements in the collection that `k` is not empty  by using `{k:{$exists:true}}` but that's turns out very slow ...

Then I add an index on `k` and trying to query by : `{k:{$gt:{}}` but that's not return the correct results.

So, how to do this counting on the collection now?

Note that I don't know the data structure of `k`.

Comment: Can you show us an explain of your query with an index and also tell us how many documents you are expecting to work on? Normally a good way is to query on a subfield you always know will exist if the field is not empty.

Comment: What version of mongodb are you using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
db.collection.count({k:{$ne:null}})
```

By the way use sparse index on k.

```
db.collection.ensureIndex({k:1}, {sparse: true});
```

Comment: That will be more inefficient as `null` in his case, if querying by `null` is slow for him then that definitely will be

Comment: That would counting all document even k is null.

Comment: No it won't... Look carefully what I wrote. If you want to see how it works behind the scenes... Replace `count` by `find` and do explain() over cursor. This will get you what you want. db.collection.find(...).explain() You would see btree cursor is used and nscanned is also equal to number of k.

Comment: Check out the modified answer.

Comment: sparse will omit null fields, how does that help? that means that the data he is querying for will not be in the index...

Comment: But for counting the documents, it works just fine. I just created a sample db and did for myself. What I mean is, for queries like these he can surely use a sparse index.

Comment: @jackalope Can k be null and would you want it to be counted as well?

Comment: k can be null and surely I don't wanna null counted.

Comment: Ok, got your point. Sorry... Bad answer. Should have thought.

Comment: I suppose, I am unsure since I have not checked this, that a sparse index in this case could diff the collection count and the index count, though the index count is not exact so I would not imagine that to be the case.

Comment: But using sparse index for only for this type of query won't be a problem. Can someone explain me how it is a problem.

Comment: Sparse omits null fields, hence why it is so useful for unique indexes to be sparse so that null fields don't throw a unique exception, it means that the data is not in index when it is queried by `null` or empty which means it is the same as not using an index, should be anyway.

Comment: But won't it be iterating over only those documents where k is defined. Say he has 100K docs in all of which he has 50 docs having k. Won't 50 be only iterated that way if using sparse index.

Comment: But he is looking for where `k` isn't there, that means the other 99,550 will need scanning otherwise the index will give incorrect results, infact I am unsure what using a spare index in this case will do, I should test that, but logic dictates that the index shouldn't do that.

Comment: Is there anyway we could determine how many documents are indexed by an index. That way it would be constant time complexity if using sparse index.

Comment: What he wrote in question suggests that he wants to count docs having `k`

Comment: hehe... this was the most rigorous discussion on SO I had till date. I enjoyed it. Thanks @Sammaye and jackalope.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using a version before version 2, `$exists` is not able to use an index.
See this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/7503114/131809

So, try upgrading your version of MongoDB

From the [docs](http://api.mongodb.org/wiki/current/Advanced%20Queries.html#AdvancedQueries-$exists):

> Before v2.0, $exists is not able to use an index. Indexes on other
>   fields are still used.
>   $exists is not very efficient even with an
>   index, and esp. with {$exists:true} since it will effectively have to
>   scan all indexed values.

The second part of that is perhaps the important bit.

It sounds like `sparse` index may be the key here...

Comment: I was technically fixed in 1.9 but that was a dev release so 2.0 is the stable: https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-393

Comment: also unable to use with version 2.2

Comment: 'also unable to use with version 2.2' - says who?

Comment: means $exists is not able to use an index even after verion 2

Answer (score 0):

Try using `$ne : null`

So, as per your code example:

```
{k:{$ne : null}}
```

Comment: This is identical with $exists without index.